# Is there anything wrong with using a CDI ViewScoped bean for caching information used in multiple pages?

Tags: jsf, cdi, view-scope

All of my pages are backed their own ViewScoped bean, but I'm finding that there are a lot of similar methods used on these pages.  For example, a user may want to view dates in their preferred time zone so each time a page is loaded, the DB is queried for what their preferred time zone is.

So my initial thought was to create a ViewScoped bean to manage this.  The timeZone value would be only be "good" for the lifetime of the page and they would be lazy-loaded to avoid unnecessary database hits:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Preference implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private SessionManager sessionManager;
    @EJB(name = "PreferencesReadFacade")
    private PreferencesReadFacadeRemote prefReadFacade;

    private HashMap<String, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * @return the user's TimeZone preference
     */
    public String getTimeZone() {
        if(cache.get("TimeZone") == null) {
            cache.put("TimeZone", prefReadFacade.getUserPreference(sessionManager.getUserId(), "TimeZone").toString());
        }
        return cache.get("TimeZone").toString();
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
<h:outputText value="#{preference.timeZone}"/>
```

Is there anything wrong with this type of methodology?  Is there a better way of doing something like this?

EDIT: Would like to add that I'm using ICEfaces and Omnifaces so if there are resources in these libraries at my disposal, I'm certainly open to using those.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is bsolutely correct - you may reuse the same bean in multiple pages regardless of its scope. If those pages are in the same scope, a bean would be reused, otherwise a new bean would be created with an empty cache. If the scope is `ViewScoped`, the bean would be recreated for every page, hence DB would be accessed first when the data is needed on after a page loads.

You may also make your common bean a base bean of other viewscoped beans, which are constructed for a particular page (they must remain viewscoped).

Or, you may inject your Preference bean into any other `Named` bean, which is used in your pages. In this way, you may inject it to a bean with any scope, but CDI will always give you the same bean for a view (within viewscope), but different when you redirect to a new page.

But your solution is equally correct, if not even better.

Answer (score -1):

You can create one `@SessionScoped` bean and hold there user preferences like time zone. Then `@Inject` it to your `@ViewScoped` beans and get time zone from `@SessionScoped`. As long as http session lives, the DB query will be done only once in the user session if you do it in `@PostConstruct` and assign to variables.

Comment: That won't work because if the database value is changed, the web UI has no idea about it and will still use the value in the session.  Hence, why I would store it in a view-scoped bean so that any changes to the timezone in the database will propagate to any new pages the user visits.

Comment: If database data changes outside user interaction then it won't be seen, but if user wants to change it then your method can also update model and current value will be seen. `@SessionScoped` will just save database queries, but if you don't mind DB transactions whenever user changes page then you can have `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Correct.  I'm just wondering whether my method of using ViewScoped beans to a) autorefresh something on new page views b) lazy-loading these so they are only refreshed when called on was a good idea.

Comment: It's a good idea, but why `@ViewScoped` and not `@SessionScoped`? There won't be much difference in `@RequestScoped` and `@ViewScoped` unless you have a lot of pages with stored data (like tables).

Comment: Because SessionScoped will not re-read the data from the database on each page load.  RequestScoped will re-read the data on each request and I don't want the changes to necessarily go "out from under" the page.